# ¿ Cómo insertar un valor a un <ion-input></ion-input>?

Tags: angularjs-2.0, ionic2

He probado a poner

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="book.name" name="name" value="{{selectedItem.title}}"></ion-input>
```

pero no lo añade. También he probado con

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="book.name" name="name">{{selectedItem.title}}</ion-input>
```

pero ocurre lo mismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.- Usas FormBuilder:** en donde puedes declarar con qué valor inicia tu forma y las validaciones se hacen en el componente.

```
this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
    firstName: ['value'],
    lastName: ['value', *validation function goes here*],
    age: ['value', *validation function goes here*, *asynchronous validation function goes here*]
});
```

**2.- Haces un binding a los campos de tus formas:** utilizas [value] para insertar un valor en el campo que necesites inicializandolo en tu constructor o hook.

> Si decides utilizar FormBuilder, te recomiendo revises cómo se usa en la siguiente página: https://www.joshmorony.com/advanced-forms-validation-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 1):

Trate de usar `[value]="selectedItem.title"`

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="book.name" name="name" [value]="selectedItem.title"></ion-input>
```

en este [`plunker`](http://embed.plnkr.co/UNOMcWDgviHz1eGddy3b/) puede ver una aproximacion con `movs`

Angular2 dice algo asi<sup>1</sup>:

```
Data direction                      Syntax               Type
   One-way                      {{expression}}           Interpolation                                                          
from data source             [target]="expression"       Property
to view target               bind-target="expression"    Attribute
                                                         Class
```

<sup>1</sup>*La verdad es que no se lo traduje porque al ver la traduccion me parecio confusa*

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html